# Locating photo links and scraping from website posting using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to use `rvest` to scrape the photo links and download all the images from postings like [this one](https://clasipar.paraguay.com/inmuebles/propiedades-rurales/feedlot-de-107-hectareas-a-90-km-de-asuncion-71526) into separate folders. However, I am stuck trying to find the links of **ALL** the images in the post (including the ones on the left) as only the active one (non-thumbnail clicked on image) is shown when I try to look for the links using `html_nodes` and `html_attr`

My code is as below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
    
url <- "https://clasipar.paraguay.com/inmuebles/propiedades-rurales/feedlot-de-107-hectareas-a-90-km-de-asuncion-71526"

photos <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("img") %>%
  html_attr("src")
```

So, my output only shows the one active image in that website posting - element **[9]** in the vector output. How can I get the links for all the images in the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, searching with regex can be quite convenient as you have a strict pattern for the image path:

```r
 url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  toString() %>%
  str_extract_all("clasicdn.paraguay.com/pictures/2016.*?\\.jpg") %>%
  unlist() %>%
  unique()

[1] "clasicdn.paraguay.com/pictures/2016/12/27/71526/1634181S.jpg" "clasicdn.paraguay.com/pictures/2016/12/27/71526/1634181L.jpg"
[3] "clasicdn.paraguay.com/pictures/2016/12/27/71526/1634243S.jpg" "clasicdn.paraguay.com/pictures/2016/12/27/71526/1634243L.jpg"
[5] "clasicdn.paraguay.com/pictures/2016/12/27/71526/1634376S.jpg" "clasicdn.paraguay.com/pictures/2016/12/27/71526/1634376L.jpg"
[7] "clasicdn.paraguay.com/pictures/2016/12/27/71526/1634456S.jpg" "clasicdn.paraguay.com/pictures/2016/12/27/71526/1634456L.jpg"
```

Comment: Yes, I get this too but the other image links are not the photos I need from the post. These are images that should start with the link `//clasicdn.paraguay.com/pictures/2016/..`

Comment: And I can only see the specific image link if I click on the thumbnail

Comment: Please see my edits.